# XPath: Make up for lost white space from normalize-space

Tags: xpath

I am currently working on a project where I need to extract some addresses using XPath. The below XPath returns all the text needed in one node due to using `normalize-space`. If I remove `normalize-space` then the text needed is returned in 3 different nodes, separating the address, city and zip, and country. Using `normalize-space` merges all 3 nodes into one node but messes up the white space of the address, as you can see below.

XPath

```
normalize-space(//table/tr/td[@class='shaded']/table[@cellspacing='10']/tr[2]/td[2])
```

Returns

```
22-13 20 St., 3nd Fl., FrontStaten Island City, New York 12101United States
```

Desired Output

```
22-13 20 St., 3nd Fl., Front, Staten Island City, New York 12101, United States
```

HTML

```
<td>
   <span class="dispaly">
      Address:
   </span> 
</td>
<td>
   22-13 20 St., 3nd Fl., Front
   <br>
   Staten Island City, New York 12101
   <br>
   United States
</td>
```

I appreciate any suggestions on how to reach the desired output.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use [fn:string-join](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_string-join.html)

```
normalize-space(string-join((//table/tr/td[@class='shaded']/table[@cellspacing='10']/tr[2]/td[2]/text()), ','))
```

Answer (score 0):

From your other questions I guess you can only use XPath 1.0, where dikk's answer will not be of help (`string-join(...)` is handy, but only available starting from XPath 2.0).

In XPath 1.0 you will have to use `concat(...)`, which can only join a fixed number of nodes. If the number of lines always is the same, you could do

```
concat(
  normalize-space(//td[2]/text()[1]), ', ',
  normalize-space(//td[2]/text()[2]), ',',
  normalize-space(//td[2]/text()[3])
)
```

It is not possible to join a varying number of text nodes. If the number of lines varies, but keeps smaller than a certain size, you could use this rather dirty hack:

```
substring-before(concat(
  normalize-space(//td[2]/text()[1]), ', ',
  normalize-space(//td[2]/text()[2]), ', ',
  normalize-space(//td[2]/text()[3]), ', ',
  normalize-space(//td[2]/text()[4]), ', ', ', '
), ', , ')
```

(and extend pattern as needed)

If a text nodes does not exist, an empty string will be returned, thus you will get `, ,` in the output. By adding this pattern at the end and cutting everything starting from it, you can work around the missing `string-join(...)` if you know an upper limit for the number of items to join, but the query gets really bloated. Maybe it's a better idea to do the concatenation outside XPath instead.